# React Native - ListView Rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing Chat app using React Native.
So for a new arrival or my reply, a component called ReplyCard is rendered in ListView
At the same time, total replies count of the thread should be displayed on the very first ReplyCard

Below code is when newNode is arrived

```
const sectionId = this.state.dataSource.sectionIdentities[0];
var nodes = this.state.dataSource._dataBlob[sectionId];

var aNode = Object.assign({}, nodes[0]);
aNode.data.meta = {
   repliesCount: this.state.repliesCount
}

this.setState({ dataSource: 
    this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows([aNode, ...(nodes.concat(
        newNode
    ))])
});
```

I hooked up renderRow callback of ListView to render my custom cell

```
renderRow(reply, sectionId, rowId) {
   console.log('ReplyCard is going to be rendered - meta', reply, sectionId, rowId);
   return (
       <ReplyCard reply={reply}/>
   );
}
```

First node and new arrival are logged in console.
I think this is because ListView only try to render affected rows
So I expected that two rows will be rendered according to the datasource change
But Only new arrival is rendered
The difference between the two is that the datasource of new arrival is completely new and I modified the datasource of first node.
I'd like to fix this bug. If you can help me, it would be great for me
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your `rowHasChanged` function that you pass to your datasource look like?

Comment: const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => {
        return r1.data.meta && r1.data.meta.repliesCount != r2.data.meta.repliesCount;
    }
});